# Create trigger in PostgreSQL - syntax error at or near

Tags: postgresql, sql-delete

I'm getting error when creating this trigger in PostgreSQL

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS districts_bdt ON districts CASCADE; 

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_fct_districts_bdt() 
  RETURNS trigger 
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
  DELETE GROUPS WHERE ID = OLD.UF_GROUP_ID;RETURN OLD;
END$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE'plpgsql' SECURITY DEFINER;
-- REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION trigger_fct_districts_bdt() FROM PUBLIC;

CREATE TRIGGER districts_bdt
    BEFORE DELETE ON districts FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_fct_districts_bdt();
```

This is my error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "GROUPS"
LINE 4:     DELETE GROUPS WHERE ID = OLD.UF_GROUP_ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be "DELETE FROM GROUPS..." instead of "DELETE GROUPS..." in line 4.